# Javascript and Regex - Strict match of words in the string

Tags: javascript, regex, matching, string-matching

I have a string like this:

```
Free-coffee and coffee-free is free coffee
```

I need to match and replace only alone word `free` but not words `{Free}-coffee` and `coffee-{free}`

Idea is to mark bad words inside string and add HTML tag `<strong>` like this:

```
Free-coffee and coffee-free is <strong>free<strong> coffee.
```

I try with space but sometimes fail if before this sentence have space.

Here is my current regex:

```
/(\sfree\s|\sfree|free\s)/ig
```

NOTE: This need to be case insensitive.

And here is example of code:

```
var text = "Free-coffee and coffee-free is free coffee";
text = text.replace(/(\sfree\s|\sfree|free\s)/ig, " <strong>strong</strong> ");
```

Help me please.

Comment: Use `text = text.replace(/(^|\s)(free)(?!\S)/ig, '$1<strong>$2</strong>')`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks for this but @RomanPerekhrest's answer is what I need and I improve that to this `(^|\s+|\“|\”|\‘|\’|\'|\"|\;|\:|\,)(free)(\'|\“|\”|\‘|\’|\"|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\s+|$)` and work perfect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following regex pattern:

```js
var text = "Free-coffee and coffee-free is free coffee";
text = text.replace(/(^|\s)(free)(\s|$)/ig, "$1<strong>$2</strong>$3");

console.log(text);
```

`(^|\s)` - ensures that `free` word is either at the start of the string OR preceded by space

`(\s|$)` - ensures that `free` word is either at the end of the string OR followed by space

Comment: Thanks! This work great! I expand this ot match also other chars and work perfect!

Comment: Here is my expanded code `(^|\s+|\“|\”|\‘|\’|\'|\"|\;|\:|\,)(free)(\'|\“|\”|\‘|\’|\"|\;|\:|\?|\!|\.|\,|\s+|$)`

Comment: @IvijanStefanStipić, glad to help